# Detect embedded Youtube player captions

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to detect whether youtube captions are on or off in an embedded player?

There is currently no way to suppress the captions if users choses to display them. I would like to show a customized message if the captions are on.

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) there is no mention of this as far as I can say.

Comment: check this page maybe it helps
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions#Retrieve_Caption_Set

Comment: @UnLoCo that relates to the video itself, what I seek is in no way dependent on the video but rather on the embedded player.

Comment: Seems it is not possible with conventional means. Could it be done via checking dom of html5 player? The captions should be there, right?

Comment: @MikulasDite HTML5 player will be embedded in an iframe, so you won't be able to access its content [same origin policy]

Comment: @MikulasDite: You would have to use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to communicate with the iframe of the HTML5 player (direct access won't be possible due to same-origin policy), the API exposed there is the same as for the Flash player.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy as pie, you can ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
  <div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/QRS8MkLhQmM?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3",
                       "ytapiplayer", "640", "480", "8", null, null, params, atts);

    var stateChange = function(a) {
            if (ytplayer.getOptions().indexOf("cc") !== -1) {
        alert("closed captions are on");
      } else {
        alert("closed captions are off");
      }
    }
   function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
      ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
      ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange","stateChange");
    }
  </script></body>
</html>
```

BTW: Google rocks ;)

this should do the trick - please don't use it in production mode - it was just a quick sum-up. You need to listen to the state you want, I'm just alerting at any event ;)

Comment: Are you sure this detects when CC are **on**, and not **available**?

Comment: @Walialu thanks, though I'm afraid flash is off limits for my use. I need both iOS and universalsubtitles support. Also as @Sergiu mensions, from the API reference it is far from clear that `getOptions` returns the clietnside visibility of CCs: https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference

Comment: Fortunately, the API works for the HTML5 API as well, but with the same problem: it returns a non-empty array when CCs are available, not when they're actually displayed.

Comment: in my example it returns cc if on and not if available ;-)

Comment: @Walialu in that case it's awesome. I'm gonna try it right now.

Comment: @Walialu Indeed it does work, that's is great. Thanks :) The only caveat is that when the user toggles captions while the video plays, it does not fire an event. I can live with that though.

Comment: http://dump.h4kr.com/test/yt-html5-cc-enabled.html here you can work around that it does toggle while watching ;)

Comment: Hi @walialu, do you think you can repost your last example?
dump.h4kr.com/test/yt-html5-cc-enabled.html seems not work any more.

Answer (score 6):

I have not found this anywhere in their api docs, but with your youtube player object you should be able to do:

```
player.getOptions("captions") || player.getOptions("cc")  //detects if captions were ever loaded at one point.
```

You can also turn it on via js by:

```
player.loadModule("captions");  //Works for html5 ignored by AS3
player.loadModule("cc");  //Works for AS3 ignored by html5
```

to turn it off:

```
player.unloadModule("captions");  //Works for html5 ignored by AS3
player.unloadModule("cc");  //Works for AS3 ignored by html5
```

to change which language if the module is loaded:

```
player.setOption("captions", "track", {"languageCode": "es"});  //Works for html5 ignored by AS3
player.setOption("cc", "track", {"languageCode": "es"});  //Works for AS3 ignored by html5
```

Comment: Nice find, thanks! Changing the cc language is especially useful when localizing sites.

Comment: Careful, it's not python, [] is truthy.  The first example isn't quite right.

Comment: When i try in console : ```document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].getOptions()``` is not a function. Hmm

Comment: @cybercoder, `document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]1` will return the HTML5 Video Element, not the YouTube Iframe API.  In order interactive with the YT player, you will need to get the ID from the iframe and hand it to `YT.get()`
For Example,

`YT.get(document.querySelectorAll('iframe[title="YouTube video player"]')[0].id).getOptions()`

More information on the YouTube Iframe API, visit:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference